# composition api - watch what object was changed

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

Is possible to catch what object was mutated?

```
const users = reactive([
  { name: 'User1', phone: '12345'},
  { name: 'User2', phone: '67890'},
  { name: 'User3', phone: '34567'},
]);
```

```
watch(users, (val) => {
 console.log(val);
}, {deep: true});
```

Now i getting a full array of users, but want to get something like:

```
users[0].name was changed
```

or

```
users[1].phone was changed
```

I have tried to use this syntax

```
watch(users.name, (val) => {
 console.log(val);
}, {deep: true});
```

but got an errors...

Comment: Consider explaining your case, the way it's done may depend on it. You preferably should track the actions that cause values to be changed instead.

Comment: Yep, in my case the best way - make a method that get arguments with index of child object of array. Thanks.